# How to print special characters from string literal as their "backslash" symbol?

Tags: c, string, repr

I have regular string literal and want to print it as it is - raw, similar how `repr()` function in Python does.

---

For example:

```c
char* text = "this thing\n";
printf("%s", text);
```

How do I get C to print

```
this thing\n
```

instead of

```
this thing
```

Comment: Your question seems to have nothing to do with the repr special method in Python, could you either elaborate on the repr relationship or take it out of the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few solutions:

1. Prepend `\n` with `\`, so backslash before `n` is recognized as normal symbol, and therefore `n` isn't included to special symbol: `printf("This thing\\n");`
2. If your compiler supports GNU extensions, use raw string: `printf(R"(This thing\n)");`
3. Write own function:

```c
void myRepr(const char* str)
{
    while (*str != '\0') {
        switch (*str) {
            case '\n':
                fputs("\\n", stdout);
                break;
            case '\t':
                fputs("\\t", stdout);
                break;
            // case ...
            default:
                fputc(*str, stdout);
        }
        ++str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly more work to do on #3 but that's what I think OP wants.

Comment: [C does not have "raw strings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850244/does-c-support-raw-string-literals).  That's a C++ feature that C has not (yet) adopted, and I'm inclined to doubt that C ever will adopt it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, I forgot to mention it's GNU extension

Comment: Is it?  I'm having trouble finding it documented in [the GCC manual's list of extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html), and my GCC 8.3.1 rejects the syntax, at least by default.

Comment: @JohnBollinger GCC 10.1.0 with `-std=gnu99` compiles

Comment: So, not a genuine option for most people.  Ok.

Comment: @Jorengarenar This was what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Full solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    printf("This thing\\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is not completely clear, but I would imagine that although the input string is hard-coded as a constant in this example, it is intended as a more general question about how to convert a string containing newlines, rather than simply a question of how to hard-code a literal backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"\\n"` to print \n u can also use it with `\t`.

```
int main(){
    char* text = "this thing\\n";
    printf("%s", text);
}
```

or you can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void newline(char* str){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){ // iterate through the string
        // 10 == the ascii code for new line
        if(str[i] != 10){ 
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        }
        else if (str[i] == 10){
            printf("\\n");
        }
    }
}

void newline2(char* str){ // same function useing in line if
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
        str[i] != 10 ? printf("%c", str[i]) : printf("\\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    char* text = "this \n thing\n";
    newline(text);
    newline2(text);
}
```