# POSIX Regex in C not matching

Tags: c, regex, posix

I am writing a program that deals with creating sockets in C and am using regex to validate the command line argument. The strings I need to match are either in the format:
`192.168.1.1:80/index.html`
or
`12.154.85.1/index.html`.
I came up with this regex string:
`^(\\b(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})\\b(\\:(\\d{1,5}))?(\\/[^\\:]*)$`
which seems like it should work. However, it's not matching in my code. Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
    char *reg_string = "^(\\b(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})\\b(\\:(\\d{1,5}))?(\\/[^\\:]*)$";

    regex_t re;

    // create regex for matching IP in form (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(:80)/index.html)
    int re_return = regcomp(&re, reg_string, 0);

    // error check regex
    if (re_return != 0) {
        regerror(re_return, &re, buffer, 100);
        printf("regcomp() failed with '%s'\n", buffer);
        printf("REGEX COMPILATION ISSUE\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

And here is the output from my program:

```
src % ./a.out www.softwareqatest.com 216.92.49.183/index.html -h
'216.92.49.183/index.html': Match Not Found!
src %
```

I've tried reformatting the code, using the `REG_ENHANCED` option in `regcomp()`, etc. and nothing has seemed to work.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your regular expression at https://regex101.com/?

Comment: @larsks yeah when i plug it into regex101.com, it says it should match. but then plugging the exact same expression back into my code continues to raise a problem

Comment: If you are using the POSIX regular expression functions, use POSIX regular expressions and not Perl regular expressions.  For example, `\b` is not a word boundary in POSIX, nor is `\d` a digit.

Comment: Don't post images of text.  It's unreadable on phones.

Comment: since you're using POSIX you should really use [raw string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24850244/995714) instead (because gcc supports it in C) to make it readable: `R"(^(\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\b(\:(\d{1,5}))?(\/[^\:]*)$)"`

Comment: And how can we test your program, if you don't provide it?  Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get better answers.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using syntax that is not supported by POSIX regular expression. See e.g. [this article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions) for a description of the syntax available to `regcomp` and friends, or consider linking against the [pcre library](https://www.pcre.org/) or a similar package that provides more enhanced syntax.

You could get your expression to work by rewriting it to something like:

```
char *reg_string = "^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}(:[0-9]{1,5})?/.*$";
```